# How do you invoke a web service from another web service using php?

Tags: php, web-services, post

So, I'm new to web programming, and for my homework I have to write some web services using PHP. Some of the web services have to use other web services, though, and we didn't learn how to do that. My professor said we should look up how to do that online.
I think to call a web service using a `GET` parameter I just need to do `file_get_contents(url)`, but I have no idea how to make a web service call using `POST`. So, how do I make a web service call from a web service using `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

POST and GET are used for data transmission and not for fetching data. To fetch data from a webpage use [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)s.